# I can read from SQL server database but can not save

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I am using Entity Framework. I can read the data from SQL server 2008 but can not save the data. Here is my connection string. I manually ran the Insert statement on the database. It works. But I can't insert from the code.

```
<add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TestDB.csdl|res://*/Models.TestDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.TestDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=TESTDEV;Initial Catalog=AttachDbFilenameC:\test\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />



       using (TestEntities db1 = new TestEntities())
        {

            Order O = new Order();
            O.OrderTypeID = 1;
            O.UserID = 29210;
            db1.AddToOrderss(O);
            db1.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: What exception / error do you get?  One possibility - does the account that you are connecting to the DB with have data writer permission?

Comment: Yes, I checked the permission. I granted all the permissions.

Comment: Ok - so are you getting an exception?  Can you post it?  That should provide some clues as to the problem. Entity Framework exceptions are generally quite helpful.

Comment: I am not getting any exception. db1.SaveChanges is not throwing any exception. It's strange issue.

Comment: Hmm that is weird... kind of shooting in the dark then... you haven't turned off ChangeTracking in your TestEntities class? http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/02/20/disabling-change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx ... otherwise I'd just start with a new model from scratch and see if you can make changes (i.e. generate a new EDMX from the database).  Try to pin down if it's an Entity Framework problem or a Database / ADO.NET problem.

Comment: agree with James, just start simple, most likely a network/permissions error. also - if this EF4, or EF1? If this is EF4, you should be using `db1.Orders.AddObject(O)`, not `db1.AttToOrders(O)`. and is this SQL Server 2008 - or SqlLite, or SqlExpress? I see `FilenameC:\test\TestDB.mdf` in the connection string..

Comment: Did you try turning on SQL Server Profiler to make sure a statement is actually being executed on your server?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the existing model and created a new database and new model. It's working fine. Thanks for the hint James.